# C# COM server interop - System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop

I have created a COM server in C# which serves a specific device and is consumed by a C++ COM client (customer application, no source available).
Customer application among other things requires periodic updates, and for that purpose function called `Notify()` is used. That function is implemented in unmanaged COM client code.

All is well when `Notify()` is called from within same thread where this notification listener object was created. But this can happen only once since C++ COM client initially asks for data just once.

And even though it asks for data just once, it doesn't seem to tolerate responses which take over a second or so. And my device is kind of slow to react, especially over network, well over a second to get a reading of some sort. Ok, I get that, it wants swift response.

So not only to achieve periodic updates, but also to relieve main thread of waiting for data, I have created a separate thread which probes a device every minute and then reports results back to unmanaged code, by calling `Notify()`.

When this Notify() is called from a different thread, I get a very nasty `System.InvalidCastException`. The exception was thrown from deep within CLR.

This was on a production system. On my own development system where I have my own C++ COM client mock up, this exception is masked by `ContextSwitchDeadlock` during debugging session. I can switch this one off, but doesn't change the fact that `Notify()` doesn't behave well cross thread. In fact, according to logs, function never returns.

What to do next?

From what I could tell from the registry, COM threading model is set to 'Both'.

I have tried to remedy the problem by creating a small C++ dll, which would act as a wrapper for Notify(). So, instead of calling directly into unmanaged COM client code using this:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    void Notify([In] uint dwCount, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.BStr, SizeParamIndex = 0)] string[] psAddresses, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeParamIndex = 0)] object[] pvarValues, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.R8, SizeParamIndex = 0)] double[] pdtTimestamps);
```

I have created small dll with just this function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void CppNotify(INotificationListener *pNotifier, unsigned long dwCount, BSTR *psAddresses, VARIANT *pvarValues, DATE *pdtTimestamps)
{
    pNotifier->Notify(dwCount, psAddresses, pvarValues, pdtTimestamps);
}
```

Which gets called using this difinition:

```
[DllImport("CppNotifier.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    extern public static void NotifyCpp([In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] INotificationListener pNotifier, uint dwCount, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.BStr, SizeParamIndex = 0)] string[] psAddresses, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeParamIndex = 0)] object[] pvarValues, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.R8, SizeParamIndex = 0)] double[] pdtTimestamps);
```

I was hoping that this would avoid System.InvalidCastException, but no luck yet.

Our C# COM server targets .NET 4.0, while .NET version installed on system is 4.7.1. Could this trigger such a problem?

I have also tried to re-register C# dll using RegAsm.exe, but this didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: How do you call CoInitialize(Ex) in your C++ client in the thread that creates the COM objects? Are all your COM objects coded in C#?

Comment: In my mock up C++ client I call it like this: `HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);`. How is it called on customer's production system I have no idea since I have no access to source of their COM client. Yes, all COM objects of my COM server are coded in C#.

Comment: This is quite important, you need to dive into COM threading matters and understand the concept of 'apartment'. CoInitialize means you create an STA apartement. Does it behave the same if you use CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)? Difficult to help more w/o a reproducing sample.

Comment: I have changed to `HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINITBASE_MULTITHREADED);` and indeed, my C++ COM client now does get notification from C# COM server from a different thread. But customer's C++ COM client I can't change. Threading model of my C# COM server dll registered in registry is set to `Both`. If customer's C++ COM client initializes as STA, does that mean if I call interface function from a different thread, it should still get marshalled back to owning thread by COM subsystem?

Comment: You're probably on the good track, but like I say, it's difficult to help more.

Comment: Thanks for help @Simon. In the end I have decided to drop C# and switch back to C++ just for this COM server part. Now notifications from different threads work properly, both on my dev system and on customer production system. Didn't even have to think about different thread apartment models or anything. Of course, now I have plenty of non COM code in C#, but that code will be put into new process. New C++ COM server will now communicate with it via named pipes. Should have started like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to marshall a interface to your object from the main thread to the worker thread, and call the Notify method using on this interface.

Define the following two member variables in your class:

```
IStream*            m_StreamThis ;
<your interface>*   m_pMarshalledThis ;
```

Before creating your thread, call the function CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream().

```
CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream ( <your interface>, this, &m_StreamThis ) ;
```

The second parameter is a pointer to IUnknown. Inside your class, which must implement IUnknown, I think that it is OK to specify "this".

The thread entry point cannot be a class member, so a common practice is to pass the object pointer as the parameter to the thread and then to use it to call a member function. I assume that you are doing this already.

In the thread, after calling a member function, call the function CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream().

```
CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream ( m_StreamThis, <your interface>, (void**)&m_pMarshalThis ) ;
```

When you need to call the Notify function, call it using the marshalled pointer:

```
m_pMarshalThis->Notify() ;
```

This will result in the function being called on the main thread.

When your thread terminates, you should of course free up the pointer m_pMarshalThis. You might want to attach it to a smart pointer class.

And of course, you should really check the HRESULT returned by both of the function calls, but that is up to you.

You can certainly find other (and better) examples of how to use these functions on Stack Overflow or other sites.

Comment: Hmm, just tried this. According to MSDN, `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` return value could be either `S_OK` or `E_OUTOFMEMORY`. But when I call it, the function returns `E_NOINTERFACE`. Not sure what this means, as my class interface is registered, guid checks out. For first parameter I use guid of `NotificationRequest` class which later provides me with `NotificationListener` pointer. Second parameter can be either `this` or  `pIUnknown`, doesn't matter, the value is the same. What would make this function to return `E_NOINTERFACE`?

Comment: I would guess that it means the object passed in the second parameter does not support the interface passed in the first parameter. You might have to cast the pointer to your interface. I have found some examples like CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream ( IMyInterface, (IMyInterface*)this, &m_pStream ) ;

Comment: Thanks @Phil for such a prompt response. Well, this really ought to work. `IStream* m_StreamThis = NULL;   HRESULT hr = CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(this->GetObjectCLSID(), this->GetUnknown(), &m_StreamThis);`. Hard to see how object in second parameter could not support interface passed by first. Of course I still get `E_NOINTERFACE`.